# C relational operators if-else

Tags: c, if-statement, relational-operators

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n=2500;
    if(0<n<1000){
        printf("no\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    int x=2500;
    if(n>0 && n<1000){
        printf("no\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("yes\n");
    }
}
```

if-else for n should be printing **"yes"**
but the output is **"no"**
why `0<n<1000` doesn't work

Comment: `if(0<n<1000)` means `if ( (0 < n) < 1000)` ... and that, in turn, is `if ( ZEROorONE < 1000)` which is, obviously, *true*.

Answer (score 6):

This expression doesn't do what you think it does:

```
0<n<1000
```

C operators don't have the concept of "between".  The above actually parses as:

```
(0<n)<1000
```

So what happens is first `0<n` is evaluated, with the result being either 0 or 1.  Then the result of check is compared to 1000, i.e. either `0<1000` or `1<1000` both of which are true so the condition will always be true.

You need to split up the comparisons as you did a few lines down:

```
if (0<n && n<1000) {
```